# Creating a relative file path for word template

Tags: vb.net

I am printing an invoice with data collected from text boxes in my form. It works perfect on my computer, but I am making this for my dad and when I send it to him, the file path is incorrect. I will tell him where to save the file, I just need to have a relative file path for that location. If anyone could help me create a relative file path to a common location, that would be great!
This is the code I use to print:

```
 Dim oWord As Word.Application
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document

        'Start Word and open the document template.
        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        oWord.Visible = True
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add("C:\Users\Dave\OneDrive\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Computer Repair\Computer Repair\bin\Debug\ComputerTemplate.dotx")
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Invoice").Range.Text = InvoiceID.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Name").Range.Text = Namei.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Date").Range.Text = Datext.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Phone").Range.Text = Phone.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Address").Range.Text = Address.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("City").Range.Text = City.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Work").Range.Text = Work.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Problem").Range.Text = Problem.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Total").Range.Text = Total.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Discount").Range.Text = Discount.Text
        oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("Notes").Range.Text = Notes.Text
```

Comment: [Application.StartupPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath) or `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're using a direct path, which of course, does not exist on the other computer.

As @Jimi suggested, use something like `Application.StartupPath`. Example:

```
    Dim oDocFolder As String = Application.StartupPath
    Dim oDocFile As String = "ComputerTemplate.dotx"
```

Then use:

```
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(IO.Path.Combine(oDocFolder, oDocFile))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, now it is saying it can’t find the file. What location should my file be in?

Comment: Your original example showed the `ComputerTemplate.dotx` in the same location as your application, your `*.exe` file, My posted answer assumes the same.

Comment: I tried moving the file out of the debug folder and having it in the debug folder and I am still getting and error that says : sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Maybe add a breakpoint to verify the `Application.StartupPath` is where you are expecting and it contains your `*.dotx` file.

Comment: I ended up making some text boxes and having it write the path in there. I saw that I had made an error in the file path in the first place, it works now. Thanks!